# How to modify existing protection of a Google Sheet using App Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet named Dashboard which is sheet protected manually except A4:C4 cells.

Now what I want is, when "Start 1-Period or Start 2-Period" in cell C6 is selected, **the Dashboard will be fully protected that means, it will include protection in cells A4:C4.**

Then after 5 minutes, the dashboard protection will go back to its previous stage, that is **dashboard is protected except A4:C4 cells**.

Please note that there are five editors in the Dashboard Sheet which will remain unchanged. For details of the scenario, please check the attached image.

```
function onEdit(e){  
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C6' && e.range.getValue() === "Start 1-Period") { 
    refreshSheet();
    onePeriod();  
  }
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C6' && e.range.getValue() === "Start 2-Period") {    
    refreshSheet();
    twoPeriod();  
  }   
}

function refreshSheet() {   
  //For protecting dashboard while scripts running
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  
  var protectionms = dashboard.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    for (var i = 0; i < protectionms.length; i++) {
      var protectionm = protectionms[i];
      if (protectionm.canEdit()) {
        protectionm.remove();
      }
    }
   var protectionm = dashboard.protect();
   var range = dashboard.getRange('A4:C4');
        
   Utilities.sleep(300000);
  
   protectionm.setUnprotectedRanges([range]);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I added my actual code as per your suggestion in the original post but it is not working at all. This block is not going through if (protection.canEdit()) { protection.remove(); } Could you please check where is the issue?? –

Comment: You can place [`console.log`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_console_log.asp) statements within your functions, pass it the variables you are interested in inspecting and run you script. To see the logs produced go to https://script.google.com/home/executions

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working at all"?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you edit cell **C6** you apply protection rules to the range **A4:C4** according to the selected value. In more detail, every time you edit cell **C6** the script will initially remove all current protections. If the selected value of cell **C6** is changed to *Please Select* then no protection is applied. Otherwise, if the new value of **C6** is either *Start 1-Period* or *Start 2-Period* you apply protection to the range: **A4:C4**.

Here is the complete solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var sh_name = "Sheet1"; 
  var sh = e.source.getSheetByName(sh_name)
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  if ( e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == sh_name && row==6 && col==3 ){

    var protections = sh.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
      var protection = protections[i];
      if (protection.canEdit()) {
        protection.remove();
      }
    }
    var protection = sh.protect();
       
     var selection = sh.getRange('C6').getValue();
     var range = sh.getRange('A4:C4');

    if ( selection == 'Please Select' ) {
      protection.setUnprotectedRanges([range]);
    } 
  }  
}
```

You just need to copy this code to the script editor, save the changes and then the script will take care of this process.

Note that my script applies to the sheet with name *Sheet1*. Change that part of the code if you work with a different sheet.

> **References**:

- [Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)
- [onEdit Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: I added my actual code as per your suggestion in the original post but it is not working at all. This block is not going through if (protection.canEdit()) {
        protection.remove();
      } Could you please check where is the issue??